# Get IdentityUser FullName of the current User in ASP.Net Webforms Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Hi guys i have this in my model:

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullNamme { get; set; }


        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

In my controller i Use :
`string userId=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();` to get the id of the current user, but how can i get the property FullName for the current user please need your help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get user manager object every where by use of Owin context manager. And by help of user manager you could get user object by ID:

```
//make sure you added this line in the using section
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

string fullname = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).FullName;
```

Comment: Doesn't work he don't know GetOwinContext(), i don't work in mvc i work in web api webforms

Comment: By calling `HttpContext.Current` you have. Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

With Identity you should use the [`UserManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) class for this sort of operation. The default MVC template will also create it's own inherited version called `ApplicationUserManager`, so assuming you haven't removed/changed that:

```
var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
var userManager = ApplicationUserManager.Create();
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
string fullName = user.FullName;
```

Comment: He say that ApplicationUserManager don't take 0 arguments

Comment: OK, slight update to use the `Create` method that should also exist in the template.

Comment: The same thing for create no overload that take 0 arguments